# unknown error from cudaGetErrorString(err)

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, memory, cuda

I get unknown error when I call cudaMemcpy in cudaT.h.
When I compile I get this warning, repeated multiple times at line 46, 50, 52:

> ./gameoflife.cu(46): Warning: Cannot tell what pointer points to, assuming global memory space

main.cu

```
#include "gameoflife.cu"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define DIM 20

__global__ void Func(CudaMem<GameOfLife<DIM, DIM> > * golDevice)
{
    golDevice->m_t->Step();
}

int main()
{
    GameOfLife<DIM, DIM> golHost;

    golHost.CreateCell(3,3);
    golHost.CreateCell(4,3);
    golHost.CreateCell(5,3);
    golHost.CreateCell(5,2);
    golHost.CreateCell(4,1);

    golHost.CreateCell(1,7);
    golHost.CreateCell(2,7);
    golHost.CreateCell(3,7);

    cout << golHost << endl;

    CudaMem<GameOfLife<DIM, DIM> > golDevice;
//  GameOfLife<DIM, DIM>* golDevice;
//  cudaMalloc((void **)&golDevice, sizeof(GameOfLife<DIM, DIM>));

    CudaMem<GameOfLife<DIM, DIM> >::CudaMemcpyHostToDevice(golDevice, &golHost);
//  cudaMemcpy(golDevice, &golHost, sizeof(GameOfLife<DIM, DIM>), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; ++i)
    {

//      cout << "Press anykey to exit.";
//      cin.ignore();
//      cin.get();

        Func<<<DIM, DIM>>>(&golDevice);

        CudaMem<GameOfLife<DIM, DIM> >::CudaMemcpyDeviceToHost(golDevice, &golHost);
//      cudaMemcpy(&golHost, golDevice, sizeof(GameOfLife<DIM, DIM>), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        cout << golHost << endl;

    }

//  cudaFree(golDevice);

    cudaDeviceReset();


}
```

gameoflife.cu

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cudaT.h"
#include <cstddef> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<size_t ROWS, size_t COLUMNS>
class GameOfLife
{
public:
    __host__ GameOfLife()
    {
        memset(m_dots, 0, sizeof(m_dots));
        memset(m_dots, 0, sizeof(m_temp));
    }


    __host__ __device__ ~GameOfLife()
    {

    }

    __host__ void CreateCell(size_t _row, size_t _column)
    {
        // need to check overflow
        m_dots[_row + 1][_column + 1] = 1;
    }

    __host__ void KillCell(size_t _row, size_t _column)
    {
        // need to check overflow
        m_dots[_row + 1][_column + 1] = 0;
    }

    __device__ void Step()
    {
        int liveNeighbours = 0;

        if(threadIdx.x > ROWS || blockIdx.x > COLUMNS )
        {
            return;
        }

        m_temp[threadIdx.x + 1][blockIdx.x + 1] = m_dots[threadIdx.x + 1][blockIdx.x + 1];

        __syncthreads();

        liveNeighbours = CalcLiveNeighbours() % 9;

        m_dots[threadIdx.x + 1][blockIdx.x + 1] = ( m_temp[threadIdx.x + 1][blockIdx.x + 1] && (liveNeighbours > 1 && liveNeighbours < 4) ) 
        || ( !m_temp[threadIdx.x + 1][blockIdx.x + 1] && liveNeighbours == 3) ; 

    }

    template<size_t R, size_t C>
    __host__ friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, GameOfLife<R, C>& gol);

private:
    __device__ __host__ GameOfLife(const GameOfLife& other);

    __device__ int CalcLiveNeighbours()
    {
        return  m_temp[threadIdx.x + 0][blockIdx.x + 0] + 
                m_temp[threadIdx.x + 0][blockIdx.x + 1] + 
                m_temp[threadIdx.x + 0][blockIdx.x + 2] + 
                m_temp[threadIdx.x + 1][blockIdx.x + 0] + 
                m_temp[threadIdx.x + 1][blockIdx.x + 2] + 
                m_temp[threadIdx.x + 2][blockIdx.x + 0] + 
                m_temp[threadIdx.x + 2][blockIdx.x + 1] + 
                m_temp[threadIdx.x + 2][blockIdx.x + 2]
        ;
    }   

    int m_temp[ROWS + 2][COLUMNS + 2];
    int m_dots[ROWS + 2][COLUMNS + 2];
};

template<size_t R, size_t C>
__host__ ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, GameOfLife<R, C>& gol)
{
    for(int i = 1 ; i < (R+1) ; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 1 ; j < (C+1) ; ++j)
        {
            os << gol.m_dots[i][j] << " ";
        }
        os << endl;
    }

    return os;
}
```

cudaT.h

```
#pragma once

#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <assert.h>

#include "cudaException.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class CudaMem
{
public:

    CudaMem():m_t(0)
    {
        cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
        err = cudaMalloc((void **)&m_t, sizeof(T));

        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            throw CudaException(err);
        }

    }

    // CudaMem(T& copyFrom):m_t(0)

    explicit CudaMem(const CudaMem<T>& other):m_t(0)
    {
        cout << "CudaMem copy ctor" << endl;
        cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;

        err = cudaMalloc((void **)&m_t, sizeof(T));

        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            throw CudaException(err);
        }
        // need to copy the memory 
    }

    static void CudaMemcpyHostToDevice(CudaMem<T>& _deviceMem, T* _hostMem)
    {
        cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;

        err = cudaMemcpy(_deviceMem.m_t, _hostMem, sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        if(err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            throw CudaException(err);
        }
    }

    static void CudaMemcpyDeviceToHost(CudaMem<T>& _deviceMem, T* _hostMem)
    {
        cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
        err = cudaMemcpy(_hostMem, _deviceMem.m_t, sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            throw CudaException(err);
        }
    }


    ~CudaMem()
    {
        cout << "CudaMem dtor" << endl;
        cudaFree(m_t);
    }

    const T* Get()
    {
        return m_t;
    }

    operator void*()
    {
        return m_t;
    }

    operator T*()
    {
        return m_t;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        return m_t;
    }

    T* const m_t;
private:

};
```

cudaException.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

using std::string;
using std::stringstream;

class CudaException : public std::exception
{
public:
    CudaException(cudaError_t _err):m_str(cudaGetErrorString(_err))
    {

    }

    CudaException(cudaError_t _err, string _file, int _line):m_str(cudaGetErrorString(_err))
    {
        string s;
        stringstream out;
        out << _line;
        s = out.str();
        m_str += " At file: " + _file + " At line: " + s;
    }

    virtual const char* what() const throw ()
    {
        return m_str.c_str();
    }

    virtual ~CudaException() throw (){}

private:
    string m_str;
};
```

Generally what I'm trying to do is to wrap the cudaMalloc\cudaFree in a class.
When I'm not using this class CudaMem everything is working just fine.

Comment: There is far to much code here and no obvious question. Nobody here is going to debug a few hundred lines of code for you. You haven't explained *where* the error is occuring or how you are building to code, your cuda version, platform or just about anything else. Having said that, this:  `Func<<<DIM, DIM>>>(&golDevice);` is almost certainly wrong. That is passing a host pointer to the kernel.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, I just needed someone else to look at this code, cause I didn't know what to look for which make question not specific.

Comment: Please write a short answer with your solution to your problem and add it as an answer to this question (that is perfectly OK). You can later accept this answer, and it will get the question off the unanswered list and make it easier to find in search for the next person with a similar problem.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with this function call :

```
Func<<<DIM, DIM>>>(&golDevice);
```

Which I sent a host memory pointer and not a device memory pointer.